# SWF fonts loading in AOT mode (IOS Ad-hoc) - ApplicationDomain.hasDefinition() returns false

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, fonts, flash

I have lots of SWF Fonts, which are dynamically loaded in my Desktop/Android app. In IOS, as we know, it's quite different, so I plan to package them with my app.
However, I'm trying to load and instanciate them, and I'm stuck for months now. I managed to retrieve classes' names, using SWFExplorer here http://code.google.com/p/swfexplorer/. I tried to get these names with getQualifiedDefinitionNames() but it returns null in AOT mode.

After this, I have to instanciate these classes. And that's where I'm stuck:

```
//SWF chargé, on enregistre les fonts grâce aux definitions récupérées
for(var i:int = 0; i < _definitionNames.length; i++)
{
    trace("ApplcationDomain has " + _definitionNames[i] + " ? " + ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition(_definitionNames[i]));
    var fontClass:Class = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition(_definitionNames[i]) as Class;
    var font:Font = new fontClass() as Font;
    if (font && font.fontName)...
```

It always output FALSE on my IOS device where my Android or Desktop versions output TRUE.
I tried with 
ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition() or e.currentTarget.e.currentTarget.applicationDomai.getDefintion() but didin't manage to load my fonts.

Any help would be GRANTLY appreciated, thanks :)